# Is there a tool to visualize PHP property annotations (comments)?

Tags: php, laravel, annotations

is there a tool to visiualize PHP property annotations (comments)?

Here is an example:

```
/**
 * @property int $id
 * @property \Illuminate\Support\Carbon $created_at
 * @property-read \App\Models\User $user */
class BlogEntry extends DashboardModel {
    // ...
}
```

So I used barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper ( https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper ) to generate these property annotations, which is very cool, but I'd like to use them for documentation and now I search a tool to do so, but couldn't find any. I am aware that my requirements are vague... so this is a bit like brainstorm, please tell me anything that comes to your mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in generating documentation for your code out of PHPDoc blocks, then look for [phpDocumentor](https://www.phpdoc.org/).